# how to deal with undefined / unprovided content-type in REST

Tags: rest, http, content-type

Now that `content-type` header (defining the request content type) is optional according to   [HTTP 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7.2.1):

> Any HTTP/1.1 message containing an entity-body SHOULD include a
> Content-Type header field defining the media type of that body. If and
> only if the media type is not given by a Content-Type field, the
> recipient MAY attempt to guess the media type via inspection of its
> content and/or the name extension(s) of the URI used to identify the
> resource. If the media type remains unknown, the recipient SHOULD
> treat it as type "application/octet-stream".

my question is

1- if `content-type` is defined in the REST service swagger file, but the request sent doesn't contain a `content-type`, shall I consider this a correct request or bad request

2- if `content-type` is not defined in the REST service swagger file, but the request sent contains a `content-type`, shall I consider this a correct request or bad request

3- if `content-type` is defined in the REST service swagger file, but the request sent contains a different `content-type`, shall I consider this a correct request or bad request (I believe not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DEFAULT MEDIA TYPE**

I prefer to have a default media type when possible. For many endpoints this is JSON. If no `content-type` header is provided then either fail with a clear message as below:

```
status: 400
{
  "code": "invalid_content",
  "message": "The content of the request was supplied incorrectly"
}
```

Alternatively attempt to process the request as JSON. If this fails, also return the same error message.

**MULTIPLE CHOICES**

If an endpoint allows a user to upload an image, there may be no default. In such a case failing as above makes most sense.

**CONSUMER FOCUS**

More important than any technical concerns is a consumer focus towards REST clients. This includes documentation and a clear code example on how to call the endpoint, and any error responses that may be returned.

Some API stacks reject requests without a content-type but may also return a poor error response that confuses and blocks client developers.

**DESIGN CHOICES**

As the HTTP spec indicates, the solution is up to the implementer of the REST endpoint. My personal preference is to completely ignore the content-type header in my code unless there are multiple choices.

Even if the default media type becomes suboptimal in future, I could handle that, either by requiring clients to use a newer content-type or by releasing a new major version of my REST component that uses a different default media type. Changes to behaviour would be published to consumers in release notes.

Comment: `415` is probably the better error here: https://evertpot.com/http/415-unsupported-media-type

Comment: I cant make a default content-type to fall back to since the content-type by definition and according to my business must be optional , but i accepted the answer specifically for the point of returning it to the implementer

Answer (score 1):

1- Does the Content-Type header in the request specify the content type of the request body or the desired content type of the response body?
Answer -> Content-Type header in the request specify the content type of the request body only

2- Supposing the Content-Type header specifies the content type of the request body, is there another header to specify the desired content type of the response body?
Answer -> you have to use:

Accept: <MIME_type>/<MIME_subtype> | <MIME_type>/* | */*
to specify the desired content type of the response body

Will the response to my request have a Content-Type header or another header to specify the content type of its body (response body)?
Answer -> Content-Type: Indicates the media type (e.g. text/html or application/json) of the response sent to the client by the server, this will help the client in processing the response body correctly.

Comment: thanks for the hint, however I was mainly asking about the discrepancy between the request content-type defined in the swagger and the one passed in the actual request ... rather than the content-type of the request vs the content-type of the response, I edited the question for more clarity